# If column name is missing, use previous column name in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

If a column name is missing, is it possible to replace its name by the previous non-NA column name (left-to-right)? The new name can, of course, not be identical, so a solution that uses the previous non-NA column name along with a simple number to distinguish the two would be perfect. If a non-NA column name is followed by two NA column names, I would like both to replaced.

I have a big dataframe with missing column names. See below for reprex.

```
# Dataframe with missing column names
tibble("con" = c(3, 3), "...2" = c(3, 2), "...3" = c(1, 0.9), "lab" = c(0.3, 0.01), "...5" = c(1, 9))

# Ideal result
tibble("con" = c(3, 3), "con_2" = c(3, 2), "con_3" = c(1, 0.9), "lab" = c(0.3, 0.01), "lab_2" = c(1, 9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could convert the columns that starts with `...` to `NA` and use `na.locf0` to change those to previous non-NA elements and with `make.unique` create unique column names by appending a suffix number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
tbl1 %>%
   set_names(make.unique(na.locf0(replace(names(.), 
             startsWith(names(.), "..."), NA))))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `grepl` and `cumsum` to create a grouping index, use `ave` with `paste` to make the change

```
names(tbl1) <- ave(names(tbl1), cumsum(!grepl("...", names(tbl1), 
   fixed = TRUE)), FUN = function(x) paste0(x[1], "_", c("", seq_along(x)[-1])))
```